# How to make user replicate my code, by making a new category?

Tags: android

I made an application for car maintenance,  where it has category for each maintenance part.  Code can be found at:

https://github.com/abdelrahman84/CarMaintenanceSchedule/tree/master

How do I make user make a new category of his own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why just simply do not simply define a JSON with parameters. You pass the JSON parameters into the new class as a parameters defining new category object.

Technically you can not have its own unique category without having it catalogue first or creating new JAVA class for each new category. If you want to keep it as unique and flex as possible and keeping it more versatile/reusable then generic category class which gets build up from a data storage source is best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I am new to programming.  So,  do you have a sample code to illustrate how this can be done,  or a similar app? Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: @AbdalRahmanFarag I would recommend creating a simple class which will accept parameters in its constructor which will include [name, type]
You can fine a more information how to create class with constructors and setters/getters function here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html